# Show error message when no data with jquery ajax get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I started learning ajax. And I have API. API return two types of response
1. Succes when I have data and when there's no data in system
2. Error (exception) when there's server error.

In API documentation I have something like this

field - success
type - boolean
response status - true/false

field - data
type - object

Inside data object I have other fields. What I want to do is simple. Show data when it is in system and show error mesage when there's no data.

According to documentation this is sample correct response when data is in the system

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "office_id": 1,
    "office_type": "s",
    "registrar_name": null,
    "registrar_mobile": null,
    "registrar_email": null
  }
}
```

and correct response when there's no data in the system

```
{"success": true}
```

or

```
{
    "success": true,
    "err": "error message"
}
```

This is what I got at this moment. When it found mydata in system it shows field properly. But when there's no data in system I got undefined. What's wrong with this code?

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://mywebsite.com/api/mydata",
    success: function(response, data) {
        console.log(data.data);
    },
    err: function(response, data) {
        console.log("no data");
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: That's because when `success == false` there isn't a property called `data`, only `success` and `err`. What are you expecting?

Comment: here: `success: function(response, data)` - this callback function only gets the response as first paramater, so `data` will be undefined in the next line. remove `data` here an change next line to `console.log(response.data);`. But check before if response.data is defined

Comment: try watching this https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/kvusadfg/ your code problem is this: error not err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your success function to only have one parameter as according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the second parameter (named `data` in this case) will be the *textStatus*.

And then you can just check the properties of the response to find out if you have data or if the response has an error

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response.err != undefined) {
        console.log("Error");
    }

    if (response.data != undefined) {
        console.log("There is data");
    } else {
        console.log("No data")
    }
}
```

Please note in your example data the response with an error still has `success:true`, this to me seems a bit silly as it shouldn't be successful if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that;

```
success: function(response, data) {
    if(data.data == undefined)
    {
        //There is no data
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me "no data" message even If there's data in the system

Comment: "If there's data in the system" I don't know what you mean but if ajax request is resulting with error, you should check the endpoint, parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with a loop, i solved the problem like this:

```
success: function(response) {

  if (response.length == 0) console.log('No data!');

  $.each(response, function (index, item) { 

   [...]

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when data available use

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [{
    "office_id": 1,
    "office_type": "s",
    "registrar_name": null,
    "registrar_mobile": null,
    "registrar_email": null
  }]
}
```

when data not available use

```
{
"success": true,
"data":[]
}
```

when error use

```
{
"success": false,
"error": {code:"111",message:"Error message"}
}
```

at client side

check as bellow

```
success: function(response, data) {
        var retrivedData=[];
        if(data.success && data.data.length){
         retrivedData=data.data;//or use data.data[0]
         }else if(data.success && data.data.length==0){
          console.log("No DATA")
          }else {
           console.log("Error in Data",data.error.message);
           }

    }
```